# Representar relacionamentos em json

Tags: json

Qual é a maneira correta ou a melhor prática para representar os relacionamentos de um recurso em json? Como exemplo, tenho as tabelas `contrato`, `representante` e `empresa` e os relacionamentos **contrato N:1 representante** e **empresa 1:N representante.**

Qual das 3 maneiras seguintes seria a recomendada? Note que na  terceira os campos precisam ter um complemento no nome (ex: nome_empresa) e isso é um pouco mais trabalhoso, estou usando desta forma por não usar nenhum ORM.

**EDIT:** Neste exemplo eu estou querendo consultar um contrato pelo endpoint `/contratos/1`

Exemplos:

1:

```
{
    "contrato_id": 1,
    "numero": 123456,
    "representante": {
        "representante_id": 2,
        "nome": "João"
        "empresa": {
            "empresa_id": 3,
            "nome": "Empresa",
        }
    }
}
```

2:

```
{
    "contrato_id": 1,
    "numero": 123456
    "representante": {
        "representante_id": 2,
        "nome": "João"
    },
    "empresa": {
        "empresa_id": 3,
        "nome": "Empresa",
    }
}
```

3:

```
{
    "contrato_id": 1,
    "numero": 123456
    "representante_id": 2,
    "nome_representante": "João"
    "empresa_id": 3,
    "nome_empresa": "Empresa"
}
```

Comment: Para que possamos acessar a url você precisa publicar em alguma hospedagem pública, não possuímos acesso ao seu localhost na porta 3000.

Comment: Ah, era só pra colocar o endpoint e acabei colocando o endereço inteiro. Corrigido.

Comment: Esse endpoint já retorna os dados como JSON?

Comment: Sim, está retornando como no terceiro exemplo.

Comment: Está retornando "flat". Essa estrutura do JSON vai seguir a estrutura definida pelo seu backend, hierarquizado de acordo com a sua modelagem de dados.

Answer (score 7):

O correto é o objeto **empresa** possuir um `array` de objetos **representante**, que por sua vez possui um `array` de objetos **contrato**:

```
{
    "empresa": {
        "empresa_id": 1,
        "nome": "Empresa 1",
        "representantes": [{
            "representante_id": 1,
            "nome": "João",
            "contratos": [{
                "contrato_id": 1,
                "numero": 123456
            }, {
                "contrato_id": 2,
                "numero": 654321
            }]
        }, {
            "representante_id": 2,
            "nome": "José",
            "contratos": []
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: E quando eu buscar por um contrato específico? Não seria melhor representar ao contrário, trazendo um contrato e dentro dele o representante e a empresa?

Comment: Essa pesquisa ficaria a cargo do seu backend, não? Acho que ainda não entendi completamente o seu cenário.

Comment: Sim. Por exemplo, quando buscar um contrato, o backend devolve um json com seus dados e dentro deles os dados dos outros recursos relacionados, neste caso, representante e empresa. Quando alguém buscar um contrato é essencial trazer também o nome do representante e da empresa. Então a minha dúvida é qual a forma "correta" de representar os relacionamentos neste json. Utilizando um ORM ele gera um json como no segundo exemplo.

Comment: Entendi. Nesse caso, a navegação ocorre ao contrário: um contrato possui um objeto representante, que possui um objeto empresa. Dessa forma, acredito que a opção 2 seja a mais correta no seu cenário.

Answer (score 4):

Fernando, pensando em acoplamento, acredito que o ideal seria ter 3 conjuntos de informações interligadas.

Imagine que depois quando você precisar alterar informações das entidades Empresa / Cliente / Contrato isso seria menos custoso.

```
{
    "contrato":{
        "1": {
            "numero": 123456,
            "representante_id": 2,
            "empresa_id": 3
        }
    },
    "representante":{
        "2": {
            "nome": "João"
        }
    },
    "empresa":{
        "3": {
            "nome": "Empresa"
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Entendi. Utilizando o ORM bookshelf.js para node.js ele gera desta forma, com exceção do id, que fica dentro da própria entidade. Desta forma parece fazer mais sentido.

Comment: Você não poderia utilizar o bookshelf.js no seu projeto?

Comment: Poderia sim, estou refatorando para utilizá-lo, mas surgiu a dúvida se tem algum padrão ou boa prática para seguir. Assim, eu poderia representar da melhor forma um recurso em json independente da ferramenta utilizada.